# Render partial with a specific variant from another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following views:

```
views/users/show.html.erb
views/users/show.html+v2.erb
```

with the variant set to `v2` on the controller, how can I render the `show.html.erb` from the `show.html+v2.erb`?

I would be expecting something similar to `formats` option available but can't find what it is. My best guess:

*stack overflow here (it tries to render itself):*

```
<%= render template: 'users/show', variant: :default %>
<h1> Additional stuff</h1>
```

*NOTE:* this is very simplified example so do not suggest to extract the templates. I am after the answer to the question - how to render a template(s) in a different variant.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by either

Explicitly naming the variant extension in the render template definition in the view:

```
<%= render template: 'users/show.html+v2.erb', variant: :default %>
```

OR

Setting the request variant in the controller:

```
request.variant = :v2
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, you should write the reusable code in a partial without a specific variant